# ArcPy vertices from each polygon and process separately as the input extent of arcpy.EvaluateRules

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, esri-geodatabase

I used Generate Grid from Area geoprocessing tool to generate a blocklist of polygons. I have the following code for retrieving the vertices from the layer. My goal, to process each feature record separately as the input extent for the geoprocessing tool. Alternatively, If I could use the model builder iteration feature selection to loop through each polygon and pass the extent to the geoprocess "arcpy.EvaluateRules_management" in ArcGIS Pro. Any other ideas?

Code below:

```py
import arcpy

fc = 'C:\\Users\\someuser\\fgdb\\Batch.gdb\\grid_index'
fields = ['OID', 'pagenumber', 'SHAPE@']

#infc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Enter for loop for each feature
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]):
    # Print the current polygon or polyline's ID
    print("Feature {}:".format(row[0]))
    partnum = 0

    # Step through each part of the feature
    for part in row[1]:
        # Print the part number
        print("Part {}:".format(partnum))

        # Step through each vertex in the feature
        for pnt in part:
            if pnt:
                # Print x,y coordinates of current point
                print("{}, {}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y))
            else:
                # If pnt is None, this represents an interior ring
                print("Interior Ring:")

        partnum += 1
```

sample code for the gp tool I need to pass the first four vertices to as the "extent" for each record.

```
# assignlocal variables
in_workspace = "https://myserver/server/rest/services/myservicename/FeatureServer"
extent = "-113.187897827702 38.0958054854392 -113.142166008849 38.1404599940719"

# run the evaluation
arcpy.EvaluateRules_management(in_workspace, "VALIDATION_RULES", extent, "ASYNC")
```

Comment: It's not clear what "processing" you want to do.

Comment: I would like to use the 4 corners of each polygon selection in the grid polygon feature as a seperate extent to process the validation tool for faster processing.

Comment: Your code doesn't attempt anything with the vertices, so it's not clear.  Are you wasting time with iterating the vertices when you could use `e = row[1].extent` and work with the `Extent` directly?

Comment: I was puzzling out how to use the vertices as extents and did not want to use the feature's extent. I'll try the "e = row[1].extent" as well.

Comment: You can store the first vertex as the min and max then walk the vertices to find true min/max, or if the vertices are in the same order, you can assume LLx/LLy URx/URy from offset. At this point, you just pasted in sample iteration code, and haven't made any attempt to use the vertices yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested as I have nothing to evaluate against but as you can see its a very simple model. All I did was connect the iterator output to the evaluate tool and the Extent parameter

[image: Model]

**EDIT:**

Try this model:

[image: Model 2]

*Note output of Get Field Value tool is a precondition to Calculate Value tool.*

The Calculate field is this:

[image: Tool]

Comment: I was testing this also, the error from the server times out pretty fast " ERROR 001400: The server took too long to answer. The client has timed out. (status code 28).
 Failed to execute (Evaluate Rules)." (there is a server setting to increase this but i don't think that is the issue). The extent that appears in the model is 0 left, 10 right, 0 down, 10 up which does not match the vertices of the polygon or the maps extent for the entire feature.  Not sure why its showing 0 and 10 for extent. I'm digging into this to get a little more detail. Thank you.

Comment: confirmed, there is no polygon at the extent that appears in the model when passing the grid_feature as an extent parameter.

Comment: @prometheus, see updated answer, does that help?

Comment: What datatype is set on the get value? String throws an error: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00526-00550-000539.htm

Comment: ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'getextent' is not defined
 Failed to execute (Calculate Value). When using Long.

Comment: The process did not execute because the precondition is false When using polygon

Comment: Get field is returning the object ID so it is type long. I would imagine the 539 error is basically down to you making a typo error, because it works for me?

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I'm carefully reviewing the syntax for mistakes. Are you running ArcPro 2.9 or 3.0, just curious. I noticed the Expression getExtent saves as "getextent()" and the code block "getExtent()" remains with the word "Extent" capitalized in 2.9. I tried a model in a .tbx and .abtx same result. I rebuilt my model to match the example verbatim with ArcPro 2.9.1. (on ArcGIS 10.9.1).

Comment: And I finally found the type! It's working. Thank you, Hornbydd you are my hero!!!

Comment: @prometheus you have learnt a valuable lesson, python is case sensitive! a is not the same as A!

Comment: Haha and worse than that I typed SearchCusor instead of SearchCursor

Comment: so the one validation rule was groovy, adding 4 predefined rules for duplicate vertices, monotonicity, duplicate ID, and domain errors for some classes and now its throwing these results. 
Value = -6281352.29789468 4551156.85895782 -6276072.29795601 4556436.85889649 NaN NaN NaN NaN
and even though it is a success it eventually times out (processing a square mile at a time. 
 ERROR 001400: The server took too long to answer. The client has timed out. (status code 28).

Comment: Not sure what changed to add the not a number on the end. Code and model and inputs are the same.

Comment: I'm not a web GIS person, more of a desktop developer, so can't comment on why these errors are occurring for you. You might to open up a new question if you are looking for help?

Comment: Thanks will do, looks like the output is fine anyways:  "Extent  ({XMin}, {YMin}, {XMax}, {YMax}, {ZMin}, {ZMax}, {MMin}, {MMax}". Now I chase down why the server times out (new question maybe). Hornbydd you are awesome, thank you again :)